# How to list all CPU IDs in a multiple core processor (with WMI)?

Tags: vb6, cpu, processor

I am using the below vb6 code to get the currently running cpu id

```
     Dim CpuId As String
     Dim objWMIService, colItems, objItem

     Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
     Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")

     For Each objItem In colItems
     CpuId = objItem.ProcessorId

     Next

     msgbox cpuid
```

This works well for a single cpu processor.
But many computers nowadays are having multiple processors, dual core, core i 3 etc.
How can i list all the existing processor ids.

I am using the processor id to make licensing for my software and when the client computers swicthes the processor to the one i have not registered, the licensed machine is being declared unlicensed.

Comment: I would expect there is one CPU ID per *physical* processor. I would not expect to see one per core. You can only find out the number of cores in one processor (see the [`NumberOfCores` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: I would not expect to see one per core... i could be wrong but apparently the cpu id does change in multiple core scenario. And then i have to wait for the customer to call me so as to register them for the other cpu-id. I hope an experienced person can clarify for me.

Answer (score 1):

The query you're using should get all the physical processors on the machine. If your software is truly installed on a multi-processor machine you could always register all processor IDs. Otherwise a quick experiment returns a single processor ID on my dual core laptop.

**MSDN ProcessorID documentation:**

> ProcessorId
>
> ```
> Data type: string
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Processor information that describes the processor features.
> ```
>
> For an x86 class CPU, the field format depends on the processor support of
>   the CPUID instruction. If the instruction is supported, the property
>   contains 2 (two) DWORD formatted values. The first is an offset of
>   08h-0Bh, which is the EAX value that a CPUID instruction returns with
>   input EAX set to 1. The second is an offset of 0Ch-0Fh, which is the
>   EDX value that the instruction returns. Only the first two bytes of
>   the property are significant and contain the contents of the DX
>   register at CPU reset—all others are set to 0 (zero), and the contents
>   are in DWORD format.

```
Private Sub GetInformation()
    Dim CpuId As String
    Dim objWMIService, colItems, objItem

    List1.Clear
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")

    'this loop runs once for each physical processor
    For Each objItem In colItems
        List1.AddItem "Processor description: " & objItem.Description
        List1.AddItem "Processor name: " & objItem.Name
        List1.AddItem "Processor ID: " & objItem.ProcessorId
        List1.AddItem "Device ID: " & objItem.DeviceID
        List1.AddItem "Unique ID: " & objItem.UniqueId
        List1.AddItem "Number of cores: " & objItem.NumberOfCores
        List1.AddItem "Number if Logical processors: " & objItem.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
    Next

End Sub
```

Result:

[image: Result]

If you don't already have it, the Win23_Processor class documentation can be found here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I appreciate this. The only thing is there is another processor ID besides the one showing of BFEBFBFF000010676 in your laptop. I am hoping there is a code or some way of knowing from the start what that processor id is. Question is how do we loop for the other processor?

Comment: @webzy I believe you are mistaken. It appears to be 1 processor, with 1 ID and 2 (in this case), cores.

Comment: Thank you. The source of my multiple ids seem to have been coming from another source.... reading the disk drive ids to make a composite id...."Select * from Win32_physicalMedia". Your answer helped me to check my coding better.